# Unable to locate text input element using selenium and python on confluence

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click inside the text area on confluence and send some text to the page. I have tried a lot of combinations to find the text input element on the webpage but have been unsuccessful. The code I am using is as below -

```
button1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mce-content-body aui-theme-default mceContentBody wiki-content fullsize notranslate page-edit')
button1.click()
button1.send_keys(x) 
driver.switch_to.frame("wysiwygTextarea_ifr")
```

> It gives an error -  no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"css selector","selector":".mce-content-body
> aui-theme-default mceContentBody wiki-content fullsize notranslate
> page-edit"}

Please help me out have been trying various combinations but nothing worked. [image]

added a snapshot for the sourcecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through your code and the DOM snapshot, I deduce that you are looking for this DOM component:  [DOM snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvmQd.png)

In which case, the code you wrote is just opposite. You have first access the `iframe` and then you can access the elements inside of it (which you did the opposite way)

Refactored your code to align with the DOM:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_id("wysiwygTextarea_ifr")))
# changing the button 1 locator to xpath as the class name is too long and may not be accurate every time. data-id attribute instead would remain relatively static.
button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-id = 'wysiwygTextarea']")
button1.click()
button1.send_keys(x)
```

Comment: Hey, I updated it to your code but I am still getting TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len().

Comment: Could you provide more stack trace and some code prior to the lines above and below, if it is ok to share

Comment: I was able to locate the element by using 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[@data-id='wysiwygTextarea']//p")